# Лицензирование програмных продуктов

Tags: лицензирование

Как и где можно получить лицензию на программу и систему (свой компьютер) к нему. Какие документы нужны для этого на Украине, в Херсоне?

Comment: Из вашего вопроса ничего не понятно, если я правильно понял, вы хотите, чтоб у вас стояло только лицензионное програмное обеспечение. Тогда напишите список программ, которыми вы пользуетесь. Сходите в любую фирму, которая торгует компьютерами (жел. покрупнее) и узнайте, сколько это стоит. Дальше нужно почистить список от ненужных и купить их. Ну, установить на ваш компьютер. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

что подразумевается под понятием:

> залицензировать

- Вы хотите зарегистрировать право
         собственности на Программное
         Обеспечение(ПО)?

тогда посмотрите под какой лицензией выпущен компилятор,с помощью которого Вы скомпилировали ПО.

- Вы хотите получить лицензию на свой
     компьютер(процессор,память и т.д)?

тогда Вам нужно предъявить патент на изобретение и авторское свидетельство

- Либо у вас есть компьютер,на котором
     "есть все!" и вы хотите легализовать
     все(шоп не посадили)?

тогда сносите все,форматируете тоже все, приглашаете сертификационных специалистов - оплачиваете покупкуустановку(стоимость привычного пиратского пакета примерно-несколько тысяч долларов), и радуетесь жизни!

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, вопрошающий желает зарегистрировать авторские права на написанную им программу. В РФ для этого есть Роспатент, в Украине какое то ведомство с аналогичными функциями. Ищите их сайт, там все должно быть написано и приготовьте денежки